# Find how many alphanumeric characters can be made up of a single number

Tags: code-golf, string

The alphanumeric characters have ASCII-values:

```
0-9  ->  48-57
A-Z  ->  65-90
a-z  ->  97-122
```

Your challenge is to take an integer as input, and output how many characters can be made using consecutive digits of that number. The character codes may be overlapping. `666` should result in `2`, since you have `66` twice.

**Test cases:**

```
Input: 5698
Possible characters: '8' (56), 'E' (69), 'b' (98)
Output: 3

Input: 564693
Possible characters: '8' (56), 'E' (69)
Output: 2

Input: 530923864209124521
Possible characters: '5' (53), 'V' (86), '4' (52)  
Output: 3

Input: 1111111
Possible characters: 'ooooo' (5*111)
Output: 5

Input: 5115643141276343
Possible characters: '3' (51), '8' (56), 'L' (76), 's' (115)
Output: 4

Input: 56789
Possible characters: '8' (56), 'C' (67), 'N' (78), 'Y' (89)
Output: 4

Input: 94
Possible characters: ''
Output: 0

Input: 1
Output: 0
```

Input and output formats are optional (yes, you may take the integer as a string).

Answer (score 11):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>8</s> 7 bytes

```
žKÇIŒÃg
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#@390n/fhds@jkw43p///b2poaGpmYmxoYmhkbmZsYgwA)

**Explanation**

```
žK       # push [a-zA-Z0-9]
  Ç      # convert to list of ascii codes
   IŒ    # push all substrings of input
     Ã   # keep only the subtrings which exist in the list of acsii codes
      g  # push length of resulting list
```

Comment: `ŒžKÇÃg` doesn't work?

Comment: @carusocomputing: Unfortunately, it fails the `1111111` test-case.

Comment: `Ã`, that makes a LOT more sense now that I read what it's doing, crap.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but your current answer fails for the `1111111` test case (output is `1` instead of `5`), and the 6-byter suggestion made by @MagicOctopusUrn actually gives the correct output.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen I think this may have been Legacy 05AB1E.

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn A very old version of legacy in that case, since your 6-byter gives the correct answer and his 7-byter not, even when using `05AB1E (legacy)` on TIO.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen is 2017 very old now :P? I guess it is. Jeez I'm getting old too, aren't I?

Answer (score 7):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), <s>17</s> 13 bytes

```
8Y2"G@oVXf]vn
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/matl#@28RaaTk7pAfFpEWW5b3/7@6qaGhqZmJsaGJoZG5mbGJsToAA) Or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/nexus/matl#S4jwqvhvEWmk5OWQHxaRFluW998l5L@6qZmlhToXkDIxszQGMYwNLI2MLcxMjAwsDY1MTI0MgYKGEACSNjQEKjU2NDE0MjczNgHrMDO3sATSliYgleoA).

#### Explanation

```
8Y2     % Predefined literal: string with all letters, uppercase and lowercase,
        % and digits
"       % For each character in that string
  G     %   Push input, for example the string '5115643141276343'
  @     %   Push current character, such as 'A'
  o     %   Convert to its ASCII code, such as 65
  V     %   String representation, such as '65'
  Xf    %   Find string '65' within string '5115643141276343'. This gives a vector
        %   (possibly empty) with indices of occurrences
]       % End
v       % Concatenate all stack contents vertically
n       % Number of entries. Implicitly display
```

Answer (score 6):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 22 bytes

```
∧Ạụ:Ạ:Ịcạ:?{tT&h∋~sT}ᶜ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/brachylog2#@/@oY/nDXQse7l5qBaSsHu7uSn64a6GVfXVJiFrGo47uuuKQ2ofb5vz/b2poaGpmYmxoYmhkbmZsYvw/CgA)

#### Explanation

```
       c                 Concatenate together:
∧Ạụ:                       "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
    Ạ:                     "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
      Ị                    "0123456789"
        ạ                Get the list of ASCII codes of that string
         :?{        }ᶜ   Count the number of results, for input [list of codes, Input], of:
            tT             Call the Input T
              &h∋          Take one ASCII code
                 ~sT       It is a substring of T
```

Comment: Unfortunately for me, fortunately for you, I don't have access to a computer at the moment ;)

Comment: @LeakyNun I have thought of shorter ways to do it, both failing because of bugs.

Comment: Can you join the two `T` together?

Comment: For some reasons, that does not work for me.

Comment: @LeakyNun The problem is that `~s` will not backtrack properly if it doesn't have the right output `T`. Putting something like `~t?` after `~s` won't work for that reason.

Comment: What if you keep `t` in place and reverse the right half?

Comment: @LeakyNun The same problem occurs with `∈` in that case.

Comment: What is the cause of this bug?

Comment: @LeakyNun For e.g. the integer 13, there are infinitely many lists, and infinitely many integers which contain 13, and it's not obvious in which order you should list them.

Answer (score 6):

## Java 8, <s>204</s> <s>197</s> <s>195</s> <s>186</s> 174 bytes

```java
n->{int r=0,i=0,e=n.length()-1,t;for(;i<e;r+=t>47&t<57|t>64&t<91|t>96&t<100|(t=new Short(n.substring(i,i++>e-2?i:i+2)))>99&t<123?1:0)t=new Byte(n.substring(i,i+2));return r;}
```

-9 bytes thanks to *@ceilingcat*.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##jVBBb8IgGL37K8gOS0ltUyi2IrYmu8@Lx2UHrKi4Sg396mK0v72j6m3JOhLI4@O9j/e@gzzL4LD56opS1jV6l9pcRwhpA8puZaHQsr/eC6jwVmC12SGDhSu2I3fUIEEXaIkMyjoT5NeeaLNorN1WmQlLZXaw93BAxiC2lfWEnith/Qxylr7CfJLeIE@YQ5w4xBOHSBTdPMiM@karfWXBM2HdrOv7554ea9/PVUAXeqZ9ijHOOe9FNF6QWYQfurcLqF8yRxZWQWMNsqLtRB/g1KxLF@CZ41zpDTq6ITyjfnwiiR8TWF1qUMewaiA8uScojetfeC@ThE9f8H0if5FYwuNhWhxxGk8TRiNOKJtQMighjzXcmhBnIiaM0DSJ2T@8JOmUD7I4G3b4ZLSjtvsB)

**Explanation:**

```java
n->{                   // Method with String parameter and integer return-type
  int r=0,             //  Result, starting at 0
      i=0,             //  Index
      e=n.length()-1,  //  Length of String -1
      t;               //  Temp integer
  for(;i<e             //  Loop over the String using the index
      ;                //    After every iteration:
       r+=             //     Increase the result-sum by:
          t>47&t<57|t>64&t<91|t>96&t<100
                       //      If two adjacent digits are a digit or letter
          |            //      or
          (t=new Short(n.substring(i,i++>e-2?i:i+2)))>99&t<123?
                       //      if three adjacent digits are a letter:
           1           //       Increase the sum by 1
          :            //      Else:
           0)          //       Keep the sum the same by adding 0
    t=new Byte(n.substring(i,i+2));
                       //   Set `t` to the substring of [i, i+2) converted to integer
  return r;}           //  Return the result-sum
```

Comment: I cannot access a computer right now, so I cannot confirm, but here are two suggestions: 1. put the initiations into the for loop. 2. instead of string manipulation, use arithmetic (use integer division to iterate through the digits and use modulo to extract the last 2 or 3 digits).

Comment: @LeakyNun Thanks for the suggestions. As for your first one, the reason the integers initializations are outside the for-loop is because I have to return the result (`r`). However, I have been able to golf 7 bytes by putting everything else inside the for-loop, in a single ternary. I will see if I can do your second suggestion later perhaps. My lunch-time is over again, so I'll have to get back to work. Will keep it in mind.

Answer (score 5):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>71</s> 70 bytes

```js
f=([a,...b])=>a?(a&(a+=b[0])+b[1]<123|a>47&a<58|a>64&a<91|a>96)+f(b):0
```

#### Test cases

```js
f=([a,...b])=>a?(a&(a+=b[0])+b[1]<123|a>47&a<58|a>64&a<91|a>96)+f(b):0

console.log(f("5698"))                // 3
console.log(f("564693"))              // 2
console.log(f("530923864209124521"))  // 3
console.log(f("1111111"))             // 5
console.log(f("5115643141276343"))    // 4
console.log(f("56789"))               // 4
console.log(f("94"))                  // 0
console.log(f("1"))                   // 0
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 47 bytes

46 bytes of code + `-p` flag.

```perl
$"="|";$_=()=/(?=@{[48..57,65..90,97..122]})/g
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/perl5#JcrLCoJAFADQ/XzFbXShYKN33hcZ6j8qxMjCkBKzRVTfPgmd9UlWYzcNsB5jygP/8DptQpaHMtuE7XunvRDGFdYIQVVBTgiU8vDNy0usIW1ABOD7G4cErs/HDOf7BFPXntpjP/TzKxpLnhmrLSlmVEVSeatlRSi1kcjwjxnEJSnUKJ1VernWeWKkGf4A)

I couldn't find any shorter way to write that `48..57,65..90,97..122`: `map{ord}0..9,a..z,A..Z` (getting the ascii value of the characters) is one byte longer. And doing `for$c(0..122){$\+=chr($c)=~/\pl|\d/ for/(?=$c)/g}}{` (looking for all numbers, but keeping only those whose numbers corresponds to the ascii value of letters (`\pl`) or digits (`\d`)) will be 5 bytes longer (note that `\pl|\d` can't be replaced by `\w` as the latter also includes underscores)).

---

Previous approach (49 bytes):

```perl
for$@(48..57,65..90,97..122){$\+=()=/(?=$@)/g}}{
```

Answer (score 2):

## PHP, 68 Bytes

```
for(;a&($a=$argn)[$i];)$d+=ctype_alnum(chr($a[$i].$a[++$i]));echo$d;
```

[Online Version](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/19f8f6270e4f8e1dd7f0db0ffc58f9e559b8a19c)

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES), <s>165</s> <s>161</s> <s>156</s> <s>154</s> 153 bytes

Yeah, RegEx definitely wasn't the right tool for the job here!

```
n=>[/\d{2}/g,/\d{3}/g].map(e=>eval("while(x=e.exec(n)){a.push(m=x[0]);e.lastIndex-=m.length-1}"),a=[])|a.filter(x=>x>47&x<58|x>64&x<91|x>96&x<123).length
```

---

### Try It

```js
f=

n=>[/\d{2}/g,/\d{3}/g].map(e=>eval("while(x=e.exec(n)){a.push(m=x[0]);e.lastIndex-=m.length-1}"),a=[])|a.filter(x=>x>47&x<58|x>64&x<91|x>96&x<123).length

console.log(f(5698))//3
console.log(f(564693))//2
console.log(f(530923864209124521))//3
console.log(f(1111111))//5
console.log(f(5115643141276343))//4
console.log(f(56789))//4
console.log(f(94))//0
console.log(f(1))//0
```

Comment: Regexp isn't that bad; A port of my Retina answer came to 78 bytes.

Answer (score 1):

## Haskell, <s>161</s> <s>157</s> <s>138</s> <s>129</s> 126 bytes

```
import Data.List
f x=sum[1|y<-nub$concat$words.concat<$>mapM(\c->[[c],c:" "])x,any(elem$read y)[[48..57],[65..90],[97..122]]]
```

I wonder if there is a better way to remove dupes of the list than importing Data.List for nub?

Comment: If you import `Data.Lists` instead of `Data.List`, you can use: `y<-tail$powerslice x`.

Comment: @nimi Is it against golfing rules if I have to download and install non standard modules? I dont think Data.Lists is standard in GHC.

Comment: As far as I know we still don't have consensus on what counts as a standard module. There are a couple of Haskell answers around here which use `Data.Lists`. It is even mentioned in the [golfing tips for Haskell](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/84388/34531) - nobody has complained so far.

Comment: @nimi Well honestly I think if I can just download any package from cabal, I could just write a function that solves the problem, upload it, then import the module in my solution. Technically I could cheat. But then certain challenges cant be done with basic GHC either like crypto stuff so I dont know.

Comment: Remember: everything used must predate the challenge, so uploading a custom module specifically made for the task won't work. Yes crypto things, image processing, graphic display, etc. are usually done with less common modules. As said, `Data.Lists` has been used in other challenges, but feel free to stick to the core modules only.

Comment: Back to golfing tips: `or $ f <$> list` is `any f list`: `any(elem$read y)[...]`.

Comment: @nimi Nice job, golfed 3 bytes!

Answer (score 1):

## Pyth, <s>19</s> <s>17</s> 14 bytes

```
l@jGUTmr0Csd.:
```

takes a string.

*-3 Bytes thanks to @LeakyNun*

[Try it!](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=l%40jGUTmr0Csd.%3A&input=%225698%22&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%225698%22%0A%22564693%22%0A%22530923864209124521%22%0A%221111111%22%0A%225115643141276343%22%0A%2256789%22%0A%2294%22%0A%221%22&debug=0)

#### Explanation

```
l@jGUTmr0Csd.:
    UT                # the list of digits [0,1,2,...,9]
  jG                  # join that on the lowercase alphabet (repetition doesn't matter)
              Q       # implicit input
            .:        # all substrings of the input
      m               # for each of those substrings
          sd          # Convert the string to a base 10 integer
         C            # convert that integer to the character with that number
       r0             # make that character lowercase
l@                    # length of the intersection of those two list of chars we generated
```

Comment: Instead of using `idT`, you can use `sd`.

Comment: Also, `l@jGUTmr0Csd.:` might be shorter (not sure if it works).

Comment: @LeakyNun Thank you, this works!

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), 52 bytes

```
&`1[01]\d|12[012]|4[89]|5[0-7]|6[5-9]|[78]\d|9[0789]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/retina#JYvLDcMwDEPv2iNFLwFM/WxNkCFUAzlkDO/uqihPJN7j8b7u/bqRDfPzLHAVnktzxFyW7exzedpZK/v4KZGtF9zbPAaZq4eQSQuW4cotwGoMwj9kQEkCBXcXLdfrT6GELw) (includes test suite)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>74</s> <s>64</s> 62 bytes

```python
f=lambda n:n and chr(n%10**(3-(n%1000>122))).isalnum()+f(n/10)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#JY3BDsIgEETP@hV7IYVKlV0ohSb2X1DS2KRdTdXvr6hzmJlkXjLbeJ7TcskJuGdInOF6WyULNHUtbfNrxgxIpJQ6Ts8083uR6jBKPqFR23hfgWFiaH0Murjz0Za0JpIN3pGJSK4l1IB/lRGxcBYdUuet@@K@C1FDdIXq97vHOvELKoEhQzOAyBUIkKyhvCq1fQA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 8 bytes

```
ØBODf@ẆL
```

Input is a digit array.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@394hpO/S5rDw11tPv///zfVMdYx0LHUMQLSFjpmOiZAFohvCKRNdEyBpCEA)

#### How it works

```
ØBODf@ẆL  Main link. Argument: A (digit array)

ØB        Base 62; yield all alphanumeric ASCII characters.
  O       Ordinal; get their code points.
   D      Decimal; convert the code points into digit arrays.
      Ẇ   Window; yield all contiguous subarrays of A.
    f@    Filter swapped; keep all elements of the result to the right that appear
          in the result to the left.
       L  Length; count the matches.
```

Answer (score 0):

## Ruby, 50 bytes

```
p (0..~/$/).any?{|n|$_[n,2].to_i.chr=~/\p{Alnum}/}
```

Reads from standard input; requires the Ruby interpreter be invoked with the `-n` option (implicit `while gets` loop).

Could be reduced to 43 bytes if it were allowed to match underscores.

```
p (0..~/$/).any?{|n|$_[n,2].to_i.chr=~/\w/}
```

Comment: This doesn't return the number of times the characters show up. Also, it fails on `111`, which should return `1` but you're giving back `0`.

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 24 bytes

```
;è"(?={9ò ¬+B+C ¬mc q|})
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/japt#@299eIWShr1tteXhTQqH1mg7aTsDqdxkhcKaWs3//5VMjQ0sjYwtzEyMDCwNjUxMjQyVAA)

Alternate 27-byte version:

```
è"(?={#~o f_d f"%d|%l"Ãq|})
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/japt#@394hZKGvW21cl2@Qlp8ikKakmpKjWqO0uHmwppazf//lUyNDSyNjC3MTIwMLA2NTEyNDJUA)